# RBASH how to prevent users exiting to normal bash?

Tags: linux, bash, rhel6, bashrc

I have set up some test account to beta implement rbash to limit users from doing to much on the server.  Currently I am using `.bash_profile` to set `bash -r` for these profiles.   But when a user types `exit` they drop into the normal bash shell.

I would like to make it so when they type `exit` to logoff the server.   Otherwise `bash -r` won't help restrict that access.

Please let me know any thought you have.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the fix for /bin/bash not showing up then do the

```
sudo ln -s /bin/bash /bin/rbash
sudo bash -c ‘echo “/bin/rbash” >> /etc/shells’
sudo chsh -s /bin/rbash ruser
```

then do this to change the user shell

```
chsh -s /bin/rbash test
```

Answer (score 1):

Set the users' login shell to `rbash` via the `-s` option of `useradd` or `usermod`, eg.

```
usermod -s /bin/rbash luser
```

if your `rbash` executable is at `/bin/rbash`.

Comment: When I user `usermod -s rbash test` login dose not work.
it updates the `/etc/passwd file to test:x:uid:gid::home/test:rbash`
I need to update it back to `/bin/bash` to allow login.

Comment: Try giving the correct path to rbash in the `-s` option. Hint: `-s bash` wouldn't work either. If it still doesn't work, try to provide a proper problem description. Hint: "does not work" isn't one.

Answer (score 1):

The exact answer to your question is to

```
exec bash -r
```

That will *replace* the login shell with rbash, not simply launch a child process..

The best answer is to change the user's login shell.